# Configuring SSIS Package to fetch connection string from the database instead of hardcoding in the connection manager

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We are using SSIS packages(SQL server 2008) in our project for various daily processes. The packages have connection managers where we have specified the connection strings including the username and password for database access.

We would like to make it centralised and more secure so that all the packages can use a common source for getting the connection string.

Can we make configure it in such a way that we can store the connection string in a database table and the ssis package can use it from that table?

Please provide your valuable inputs.

Comment: Have you tried anything or performed any research at all on this topic?

Comment: @billinkc I have read about the package configuration option in BIDS. One option that provides is reading the configuration from a XML file. Is there any option where we can get it from the database?

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is a property of the connection manager so you can certainly link them to a variable through an expression.
 You can read first the table with the connection strings (I'm assuming this table is in a different db :) and then populate the variable linked to the connection string.